# Unable to format SD card

Tags: disk-utility, sd-card

I was using my SD card on my phone. One fine day it showed a message that it was corrupted. I put the card in an adapter and plugged it into my iMac.

[image: There was 3 GBs free]

I was able to read and copied all I need. I decided to format it anyway and used disk utility to do so.

[image: I renamed it to SD]
It said that it had finished erasing, but all the files were still on it.

[image: Note that I changed the name to SD but it is still NO NAME]

I tried deleting each folder. But when I ejected and put it back in, the files are still there. I can't format it via my phone either and I am too scared to use the terminal for erasing. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It's dead.
Smash it to prevent your data being stolen & throw it away.

If a write error occurs, the firmware controller will switch over to read-only mode to prevent further data loss. This is to all intents & purposes, irreversible.

Comment: So I will be able to get all my things back from the card, even though it is dead?

Comment: It will still be technically readable - though you won't know until you actually try it what damage has already occurred. It's not writeable, which is why after a format it's still as it was; for some reason devices *think* they can write to it but actually cannot. It's a common issue when they fail this way.